# Flags deprecated in Tensorflow 2.0, what is the best alternative?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, absl-py

`tf.app.flags` and `tf.app.run` from Tensorflow 1 were removed from Tensorflow 2. Is there a better alternative than using `tf.compat.v1.flags` given I am writing the script from scratch.

What's the best way to do this? Should I just stick with `argparse` and run `main()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `tf.app.flags`, it is recommended to use [abseil-py](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py).
An example,

```
from absl import app
from absl import flags
from absl import logging

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

flags.DEFINE_string('flag', None, 'Text')

def main(argv):
  logging.info('flag is %s.', FLAGS.flag)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(main)
```

Comment: hey thanks so much for the response. May I ask what is the justification to go out of the standard module "argparse"? Like what are the advantages?

Comment: One of the advantages is distributed flags. Also,`abseil-py` has a compatible syntax with `tf.app.flags`, `tf.app.logging`, etc from `TensorFlow 1.*`.